# Gradle custom task in build.gradle

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle custom task with name `customTask` to generate a couple of files.

Even if I manually delete the generated files or build directory or do a gradle clean, the UP-TO-DATE status remains true and the task is not running again.

Also, I have made `compileJava` `dependsOn` `customTask`.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can share you build file?

But if all you wan to do is clean some files up before compile, you can look at extending the compile task with a doFirst

e.g. https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html

`compile.doFirst {
    if (true) { throw new StopExecutionException() }
}`

Answer (score 0):

write

`outputs.upToDateWhen { false }`

inside task, this will force task to run even if is UP-TO-DATE